# Discriminant function for Gaussian distribution

Tags: r, algorithm

Hello community i have the following error:

```
Error in X - Q$Mu : argument non numérique pour un opérateur binaire
Called from: transpose(X - Q$Mu)
```

Here is my code(r language), i hope it will be helpful i want to simulate a dataset and applying the gaussian distribution , but it gives me the error above

```
library(MixSim)
library(rlist)
Q <- MixSim(MaxOmega = 0.0, K = 2, p = 2)
A <- simdataset(n = 500, Pi = Q$Pi, Mu = Q$Mu, S = Q$S)
A
vk=data.frame(A$id)
v=count(vk,1)
v ########### count the elements of eah class (this exemple has 5 classes)
v[1,2]###### elements for class 1
v[2,2]######## elements for class 2

g <- function(X,sigma,i) {
  return((1/2)*transpose(X-Q$Mu)*solve(Q$S[,,i])*(X-Q$Mu))-(1/2)*ln(sigma)+ln(v[i,2]/500)
}

g(A,sigma,1)
sigma=Q$Mu
mahalanobis(A,  sigma, Q$S)
Q$Mu
ln(sigma)
Q$Mu
```

I want it to calculate this function
[Discriminant Gaussian distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0bph.png)

P is the probability   , Q$Mu is the mean
Q$S[,,i] is the covariance matrix for class i

Comment: double-check the brackets in your function: it seems there's a closing parenthesis placed too early in the `return()` statement

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by `X-Q$Mu` part of your function. As you call it as `g(A,sigma,1)`, it is essentially `A-Q$Mu`. `A` is a list and `Q$Mu` is a matrix - you can't subtract a matrix from a list.
You probably meant the matrix part of `X`, i.e. `X$X`. But even then, `Q$mu` is a matrix with incompatible dimensions - you can't subtract it.
Additionally, your `return()` statement seems to have a typo - there's additional part after the closing parenthesis, it won't be returned.

Comment: So how can i convert a list to matrix

Comment: `transpose()` takes list as its input. You need to define what do you want to have there

Comment: i want a matrix

Comment: you need to explain in details what do you need from that code (or give us the source of that piece) - we can't help otherwise.

Comment: I want to write a code that calculate the discriminant function please see the edited question

Comment: your `Q$Mu` is a 2x2 matrix - it is supposed to be a single number, right?

Comment: It's 2x2 matrix

Comment: your `A$X` is 500x2 matrix, R can't subtract matrices of different dimensions

Comment: So i must do reshape or how can i calculate g using the expression in the picture

Comment: well you need to get understanding of the formula - it's a purely math question, not about R. Maybe worth asking at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Perhaps they will know how to resolve my problem ,thank you anyway